# Parse Datetime with +0 timezone

Tags: python, datetime, parsing, timezone-offset

I have the following Datetime string: `Dec 03 2020 01: +0` which I want to parse into a datetime object.

`dtObj = datetime.strptime("Dec 03 2020 01: +0", '%b %d %Y %I: %z')`

Checking the Documentation, this should work but I get the following error:

`ValueError: time data 'Dec 03 2020 01: +0' does not match format '%b %d %Y %I: %z'`

Any ideas what I have overseen?

Thanks in advance

Comment: On the contrary, the docs say this shouldn't work. `%z` is `UTC offset in the form ±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]]`

Comment: what would be the alternative then? I dont find anything similar to `%z`

Comment: That datetime string itself looks wrong, theres no minute mark past the colon.
If that was a typo and youre still looking for a solution, you could use something like regex to exclude the +0 at the end or just split the string if all your inputs end with a +0

Comment: @KevinLee `datetime.strptime("Dec 03 2020 01: +00:00", '%b %d %Y %I: %z')` works. Which is strange. The string is definitely weird though

Comment: @codedor why do you want such an unusual offset? Never mind the missing minutes? Where does this string come from?

Comment: This comes from Steam. This endpoint: https://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?appid=730&market_hash_name=Sticker%20|%20EliGE%20(Gold)%20|%20Antwerp%202022

Cuts off the Minutes, because (i guess) it's always xx:00:00

Edit: You must be logged into steam to see the result. But it's not me making this decision ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas what I have overseen?

[strftime.org](https://strftime.org/) claims that `%z`

> UTC offset in the form ±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]] (empty string if the object
> is naive).

this mean that it must contain at least 4 digits after `+` or `-` (`HHMM` part, which is compulsory), taking this is account `Dec 03 2020 01: +0` is not compliant with used format string, whilst `Dec 03 2020 01: +0000` is

```
import datetime
dtObj = datetime.datetime.strptime("Dec 03 2020 01: +0000", '%b %d %Y %I: %z')
print(dtObj)
```

gives output

```
2020-12-03 01:00:00+00:00
```